# How can I confirm that ClassPathXmlApplicationContext finds a file?

Tags: java, spring

We have an app that does not run in a web container so I am trying to start Spring up.  In the "main" function we have this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException, AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException, AuthorizationException {

    // starting up spring...
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/applicationContext.xml");
    DataSourceTransactionManager dstm = applicationContext.getBean("markiscool", DataSourceTransactionManager.class);
    dstm.toString();
}
```

And my applicationContext.xml contains:

```
<bean id="markiscool" class="blah.entities.LocationEntity" />
```

The app, on startup, logs this:

> [INFO] ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@295cd6e5:
>   startup date
>   [Thu Dec 17 10:28:28 CST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
>   Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'markiscool' is defined

I have tried putting garbage in the xml file but it doesn't fail so it must not be finding the file.  Also, the file is on the classpath:

[image]

I have also stuck the file in about every place I can think of.  It does not load.  Help!

Comment: Where is the file located? Is this a Maven project?

Comment: It is a maven project.  Does that matter?  It is in the "conf" folder...

Comment: Yep it matters a lot :). Put this file under `src/main/resources` instead.

Comment: I had to add the folder, but I put it there and, no joy...

Comment: Since you're using Eclipse, you should verify that (1) the build path includes the resources folder, and (2) it includes all files in that folder. The second is probably the problem: for some reason the `m2e` plugin doesn't configure Eclipse to automatically update resources.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) Put applicationContext.xml into the config folder

[image: config folder]

2) Tell Maven to include applicationContext.xml in the jar it creates

[image: POM include statement]

3) Use the function ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to pull in the file

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:conf/applicationContext.xml");
```

Note: FileSystemXmlApplicationContext will not work if you are trying to access a file inside of a jar. For this reason I recommend using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext because it works whether you are running the project in eclipse or via the jar

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`:

```
  ApplicationContext applicationContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/conf/applicationContext.xml");
```

Instead of:

```
  ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/applicationContext.xml");
```

Comment: Bam.  This did the trick although the above example is for a Web container.  I used this:  "ApplicationContext applicationContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/conf/applicationContext.xml");" and it worked just fine.  Thanks!

Comment: In deployment you can use relative path

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Right click -> properties -> Deployment Assembly

Put an entry: conf -> /

try
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");